# python sleep for second to throttle requests

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a celery periodic task which has a function call inside it i need to make the code sleep for a second for every 20 emails sent how can i achieve that.

```
 @app.task(bind=True)
 def send_email_reminder_on_due_date(self):
      send_email_from_template(
            subject_template_path='emails/subject.txt',
            body_template_path='emails/template.html',
            template_data=template_data,
            to_email_list=email_list,
            fail_silently=False,
            content_subtype='html'
        )
```

i have some condition before **send_email_from_template** i.e fetching records from database whose due_date is today and i will be sending email for all the records which i fetch let's say i have 30 records for which i need to send an email to so i would do sleep for 1 second after the email function gets executed for 20 records.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

1. retrieve 20 records from database (`LIMIT 20` by mysql)
2. wait 1 seconds

```py
import time
time.sleep(1) # Sleep for 1 second
```

3. repeat the first step

With this solution, it is also a given that newer emails in the database, e.g. they can be revoked or even modified.

> Is there any other way we could that without limiting it on the database level by Happy

```py
records = mycursor.fetchall()

i = 0
for record in records:
  send_email(record)
  i = i + 1
  if i % 20 == 0:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is there any other way we could that without limiting it on the database level